# How does the google geometry calculator work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I recently saw the Google inbuilt geomertry calculator. When I search "area of circle" of any other shape, Google has a in-built calculator in which the user can fill the radius and it will provide the area. So when when the user types a value, the calculator provides the area automatically without the user needing to click on a submit button, when the user changes the radius, the calculator automatically recalculates the area instantly.

(Check  [example](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=area+of+circle) out if you want to test it)

So how does it work? Is it simply JavaScript or AJAX or some other web technology?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a mathematical calculation which can done using javascript alone. There is no need of AJAX as I guess. You get the input and calculate and display it with drawing even using canvas.

What you need is formulas as in the link you need `A = π * (r * r)` for circle

and for square `A = a * a` where a is the length of a side.

Using keyup call backs you can easily make it without using a button. See a example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U9reT/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="radius" />
<div id="res"> Area is <span> 0 </span> </div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#radius").keyup(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var r = parseInt($(this).val(),10);
        var a = (r*r) * 3.142;
        $("#res span").html(a);
    });
});
```

javascript

```
var rad = document.getElementById("radius");
rad.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    var r = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    var a = (r*r) * 3.142;
    alert(a);// display it in a element instead of alert
}, false);
```

Comment: Yeah I was able to pull of the math and get the result. But the result is only displayed when the user hits submit, So can I get ride of the submit button and when the user changes the radius the result changes instantly.

Comment: Yeah so you use JQuery. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes I used jquery. But i'm giving you a javascript version as well.